# Internet Explorer always using NTLM instead of Kerberos

Tags: internet-explorer, authentication, kerberos, ntlm, webhdfs

I am trying to browse my `HDFS` system from internet explorer but for some reason it is always using `NTLM` instead of `Kerberos`, so I receive the message

> GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did
>   not find the right tag)

If I browse from Firefox (after setting the properties `network.auth.use-sspi=false` and `network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris=https://pd-vrt-21488`) everything works fine.

In `IE` I added `https://pd-vrt-21488:50470` to the list of local intranet sites and enabled “`Integrated Windows Authentication`”.

Looking at the request by using Fiddler I see the difference between Firefox using `Kerberos` and `IE` using `NTLM`.
Firefox header:

```
Authorization: Negotiate YIICyAYGKwYB .....much more character.....V2HbPG57vXnQ7Vm7ba7MTJ7qzJ7zA7+1foY=
```

IE header:

```
Authorization: Negotiate TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAl4II4gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAbEdAAAADw==
```

Any ideas what’s wrong ?

Comment: Did you test it in a different machine?

Comment: I used different client machines.

Comment: @Johan Did you find any solution?

Comment: wireshark can help identify the issue because it can decode the token